# Occasional Sudden Stop While Running Program

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

I am trying to create a simulation of a large battle between a population of Pokemon. For the sake of providing an example, I will use two Pokemon, named pokemon1 and pokemon2. I want the program to work like the following:

- pokemon1 and pokemon2 will be compared based on their combatScore, which is a score based off of their basic attributes, such as speed, attack, defense, etc.
- pokemon1 and pokemon2 will be randomly paired up with each other and be compared.
- if pokemon1 has a higher combatScore than pokemon2, than pokemon1 advances to the next round (and is removed from the general population and placed into a "victorious" population), and pokemon2 is removed from the general population and added to a "vanquished" population.
- pokemon1 then gains some attributes based off of the traits of pokemon2.
- if pokemon2 (defeated) is legendary, however, they must lose a total of three times before they are finally added to the vanquished population.
- if pokemon1 (victorious) was not legendary but has won three times, it becomes legendary and must therefore lose three times before it is added to the vanquished population.

The rounds are repeated with fewer and fewer victorious populations until there is only one victor left standing.

I have created a do-while loop that will randomly retrieve two Pokemon from the population and compare them based off a number of different conditions using if-else branches:

1. legendary pokemon2 beats legendary pokemon1
2. pokemon2 beats legendary pokemon1
3. legendary pokemon2 beats pokemon1
4. pokemon2 beats pokemon1

And vice versa. The problem I am running into is this: Most of the time, the program runs clean, and round 1 is complete. All of the battles are written to a pokemon.txt file clearly stating who won. Sometimes, however, the program will begin to run and stay in a running state. When I go to check the .txt file, it will be stopped writing mid-sentence around the same location (around line 275).

For now, I just want to run the first round. Here is the code that runs this simulator:

```
  do {
        Pokemon pokemon1;
        Pokemon pokemon2;
        pokemon1 = population.get((int) (Math.random() * population.size()));
        do {
            pokemon2 = population.get((int) (Math.random() * population.size()));
        } while (pokemon1.getId() == pokemon2.getId());


        if (pokemon2.getCombatScore() > pokemon1.getCombatScore()
                && pokemon2.isLegendary() && pokemon1.isLegendary()) {
            bufferedWriter.write("The legendary " + pokemon2.getName() + " defeats the legendary " +
                    pokemon1.getName() + " with a combat score of " + pokemon2.getCombatScore() + "!");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            /* pokemon2 gains xp from winning */
            pokemon2.incAttack(pokemon1.getCombatScore());
            pokemon2.incDefense(pokemon1.getCombatScore());
            pokemon2.addVict();

            victorious.add(pokemon2);
            population.remove(pokemon2);

            pokemon1.addLoss();

            if (pokemon1.numLoss == 3) {
                defeated.add(pokemon1);
                population.remove(pokemon1);
            }
        }

        else if (pokemon2.getCombatScore() > pokemon1.getCombatScore()
                && pokemon1.isLegendary()) {
            bufferedWriter.write(pokemon2.getName() + " defeats the legendary " +
                    pokemon1.getName() + " with a combat score of " + pokemon2.getCombatScore() + "!");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            /* pokemon2 gains xp from winning */
            pokemon2.incAttack(pokemon1.getCombatScore());
            pokemon2.incDefense(pokemon1.getCombatScore());

            pokemon2.addVict();
            if (pokemon2.numVict == 3) {
                bufferedWriter.write(pokemon2.getName() + " has become legendary!");
            }

            victorious.add(pokemon2);
            population.remove(pokemon2);

            pokemon1.addLoss();
            if (pokemon1.numLoss == 3) {
                defeated.add(pokemon1);
                population.remove(pokemon1);
            }
        }

        else if (pokemon2.getCombatScore() > pokemon1.getCombatScore()
                && pokemon2.isLegendary()) {
            bufferedWriter.write("The legendary " + pokemon2.getName() + " defeats " +
                    pokemon1.getName() + " with a combat score of " + pokemon2.getCombatScore() + "!");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            /* pokemon2 gains xp from winning */
            pokemon2.incAttack(pokemon1.getCombatScore());
            pokemon2.incDefense(pokemon1.getCombatScore());
            pokemon2.addVict();

            victorious.add(pokemon2);
            population.remove(pokemon2);

            pokemon1.addLoss();

            defeated.add(pokemon1);
            population.remove(pokemon1);
        }
        else if (pokemon2.getCombatScore() > pokemon1.getCombatScore()) {
            bufferedWriter.write(pokemon2.getName() + " defeats " +
                    pokemon1.getName() + " with a combat score of " + pokemon2.getCombatScore() + "!");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            /* pokemon2 gains xp from winning */
            pokemon2.incAttack(pokemon1.getCombatScore());
            pokemon2.incDefense(pokemon1.getCombatScore());

            pokemon2.addVict();
            if (pokemon2.numVict == 3) {
                bufferedWriter.write(pokemon2.getName() + " has become legendary!");
            }

            victorious.add(pokemon2);
            population.remove(pokemon2);

            pokemon1.addLoss();

            defeated.add(pokemon1);
            population.remove(pokemon1);
        }
        else if (pokemon1.getCombatScore() > pokemon2.getCombatScore()
                && pokemon2.isLegendary() && pokemon1.isLegendary()) {
            bufferedWriter.write("The legendary " + pokemon1.getName() + " defeats the legendary " +
                    pokemon2.getName() + " with a combat score of " + pokemon1.getCombatScore() + "!");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            /* pokemon2 gains xp from winning */
            pokemon1.incAttack(pokemon2.getCombatScore());
            pokemon1.incDefense(pokemon2.getCombatScore());
            pokemon1.addVict();

            victorious.add(pokemon1);
            population.remove(pokemon1);

            pokemon2.addLoss();

            if (pokemon2.numLoss == 3) {
                defeated.add(pokemon2);
                population.remove(pokemon2);
            }
        }

        else if (pokemon1.getCombatScore() > pokemon2.getCombatScore()
                && pokemon2.isLegendary()) {
            bufferedWriter.write(pokemon1.getName() + " defeats the legendary " +
                    pokemon2.getName() + " with a combat score of " + pokemon1.getCombatScore() + "!");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            /* pokemon2 gains xp from winning */
            pokemon1.incAttack(pokemon2.getCombatScore());
            pokemon1.incDefense(pokemon2.getCombatScore());

            pokemon1.addVict();
            if (pokemon1.numVict == 3) {
                bufferedWriter.write(pokemon1.getName() + " has become legendary!");
            }

            victorious.add(pokemon1);
            population.remove(pokemon1);

            pokemon2.addLoss();
            if (pokemon2.numLoss == 3) {
                defeated.add(pokemon2);
                population.remove(pokemon2);
            }
        }

        else if (pokemon1.getCombatScore() > pokemon2.getCombatScore()
                && pokemon1.isLegendary()) {
            bufferedWriter.write("The legendary " + pokemon1.getName() + " defeats " +
                    pokemon2.getName() + " with a combat score of " + pokemon1.getCombatScore() + "!");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            /* pokemon2 gains xp from winning */
            pokemon1.incAttack(pokemon2.getCombatScore());
            pokemon1.incDefense(pokemon2.getCombatScore());
            pokemon1.addVict();

            victorious.add(pokemon1);
            population.remove(pokemon1);

            pokemon2.addLoss();

            defeated.add(pokemon2);
            population.remove(pokemon2);
        }
        else {
            bufferedWriter.write(pokemon1.getName() + " defeats " +
                    pokemon2.getName() + " with a combat score of " + pokemon1.getCombatScore() + "!");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            /* pokemon2 gains xp from winning */
            pokemon1.incAttack(pokemon2.getCombatScore());
            pokemon1.incDefense(pokemon2.getCombatScore());

            pokemon1.addVict();
            if (pokemon1.numVict == 3) {
                bufferedWriter.write(pokemon1.getName() + " has become legendary!");
            }

            victorious.add(pokemon1);
            population.remove(pokemon1);

            pokemon2.addLoss();

            defeated.add(pokemon2);
            population.remove(pokemon2);
        }

    }while (population.size() != 0);
```

And here is a sample screenshot of the .txt file when it is running "forever":

```
272 Stoutland defeats Loudred with a combat score of 5415!
273 Croconaw defeats Electrike with a combat score of 3272!
274 Rapidash defeats Meditite with a combat score of 7390!
275 Jynx defeat
```

I've tried debugging and stepping through each condition to make sure they work. I am pretty confident they all do. Does the problem lie elsewhere? Is it a problem that it runs into when there are an odd number of Pokemon in the population? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To assist with your debug, I suggest you add bufferedWriter.flush() after each time you write to it.  This might lead to an insight.  Currently there would still be some text held in the buffered writer, which makes it difficult to see where things are up to.

Comment: Also, I'd be suspicious of your while look involving math.random.  Maybe put some debug printing in there to see if it's stuck.

Comment: Added a debug statement to my while loop, and I think the problem lies there. Now, whenever the program seems to be running forever, it looks like it has something to do with the logic within the while loop. Perhaps the problem is it is searching for another Pokemon when there is only one left in the general population?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when choosing both contenders for the fight, you enter a loop that never exits:

```
pokemon1 = population.get((int) (Math.random() * population.size()));
do {
    pokemon2 = population.get((int) (Math.random() * population.size()));
} while (pokemon1.getId() == pokemon2.getId());
```

This seems fine, but what happens if the population has only one pokemon? It will never choose a second one and never exit the loop.

As for why it stops writing mid-sentence, you are using a buffered writer, which doesn't necessarily flush it's contents to the file immediately. While you are stuck in the loop, the writer is waiting for more info to write and it's keeping the rest in it's buffer. A call to flush() would help you with this particular issue, but ensuring there are enough pokemon for a fight is the bigger problem.

Comment: I  was just discovering this problem as I was getting the notification that your replied. I neglected to address that issue initially. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Always happy to help!